# Mirror moving near the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reflection, geometric-optics

Suppose I am looking at a moving mirror, the image will move at twice the speed of the mirror but what if the mirror was to move with half the speed of light? How will my image look and what if the mirror exceeded the half the speed of light? Will the image lag from my point of view?

Answer (score 4):

The image will appear to move at the speed of light. If you move the mirror faster, the image will appear to exceed the speed of light.

Special relativity only forbids physical objects from going faster than the speed of light. There is no contradiction if non-physical objects such as images, laser beams, or shadows travel faster than light.

Comment: Of course, you couldn't see the reflection with your eyes in any event, since the frequencies of the light would be Doppler-shifted by a factor of $(1+\beta)/(1-\beta)$ due to the motion of the mirror.  I suppose you'd get a nice view of yourself in the infrared if the mirror was reflective enough in that range.

Comment: @benrg I think we're assuming the mirrors are moving in different directions. I am assuming the mirror is moving with a velocity in the plane of the mirror's surface. In that case it's certainly possible for the image to "pan" at speeds greater than light. It's essentially the lighthouse paradox. And it's an important point that there's no problem with images travelling faster than light so long as it doesn't require any particles travelling faster than light.

Comment: @Chris Oh I see. Well, I'll leave my answer up; it's right too depending on what the question was.

Answer (score 1):

In the rest frame of the mirror, by symmetry your mirror image's velocity is the negative of yours. So in your rest frame, the mirror image moves at $\frac{1/2+1/2}{1+(1/2)^2}c=4c/5$.

That's the speed that would be measured by a radar speed gun, for example (although only if the radar signal is not detected by the gun when it's reflecting off the "mirror image" (which is actually you), since otherwise you're measuring the speed of the mirror instead).